# % like % not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in database which has a column named title. And in that table imagine I have a car name saved for example Toyota fj cruiser. Now If I search using % like % and search like % Toyota % it would return properly the result Toyota fj cruiser. Now if I search like % Toyota f % it would again return properly.

The issue arises when I try to search like % Toyota cru % then it does not return the title that is Toyota fj cruiser.

```
$sql_sticky = mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `category`, `subcategory`, `type`, `times` FROM `product_search1` WHERE `title` LIKE '%$key%' order by times desc limit 30");
```

Why this would happen ?

Comment: Post the code what you tried

Comment: @SougataBose Then if I had to achieve this what should be done in such case ?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam added please check thank you.

Comment: Stop using deprecated mysql API. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @Jens its clients old code and I know its depreciated :(

Comment: Built the like using `"%". implode("%",explode(" ",$key))."%"` to match any words. Also be warned that this sort of wildcard matching is really slow so if you have lots of data consider using proper search like ElasticSearch

Comment: I have nominated to reopen this question since you have added the code

Comment: You should check the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys for your response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to search by breaking the word sequence.

To achieve what you need, one solution will be to split the words and add `%` pattern to it.

So your keyword should become `%Toyota%cru%`

You can first replace the words i.e. `spaces` with `%` in `PHP` as follows:

```
$str = 'Toyota cru';
$queryStr = str_replace(' ', '%', $str);

$sql = "SELECT car_name FROM tbl_name WHERE carname LIKE '%$queryStr%'";
```

Comment: Thank you Samir for your time and sharing your knowledge. Awesome it works now :)

Comment: You are welcome! Happy coding!